# Let $N=\{1,2...n\}$ and $i\in N$, show that $\sum_{i\notin S\subseteq N}\frac{1}{n \binom{n-1}{|S|}}=1$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, game-theory

I came across this problem while studying game theory. In this case, $i$ is a dummy player of a TU-game, but I think this identity is independent of the choice of $i$.

> Let $N=\{1,2...n\}$ and $i\in N$, show that $$\sum_{i\notin S\subseteq
>  N}\frac{1}{n\binom{n-1}{|S|}} =1$$

I've tried some algebraic proofs but got nowhere, and with combinatorial proofs I didn't get to the answer either. I haven't really had any practice with combinatorial proofs dealing with subsets of this kind. I did find that the amount of subsets of $N$ that *do not* contain $i$ is equal to $2^{n-1}$, but I couldn't find out a way to say anything about the size of these subsets.

Comment: **Hint:** For each size $s$ there are precisely $\tbinom{n-1}{s}$ such subsets.

Comment: Also, the identity does not hold; try plugging in $n=3$. In general the sum equals $\tfrac1n\tbinom{2n}{n}$. Use the [Vandermonde identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity) for binomial coefficients.

Comment: @Servaes You are right. I made a typo; one is supposed to divide by the binomial, not multiply. I've corrected it now.

Comment: Then the hint will get you there.

Comment: @Servaes Thank you. Using the hint I figured it out, I didn't need the $2^{n-1}$ after all. Now I just have to find a way to prove/understand the hint.

Comment: @Marc The hint is basically the definition of a binomial coefficient.

Comment: @Milten I saw, maybe I have a habit of commenting too quickly. A quick combinatorial proof got me to where I needed to be. I'm sure an algebraic approach would also work.

Answer (score 1):

Hint : note that 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{i\notin S\subseteq N}= \sum_{S\subseteq N-\{i\} } =\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}   \sum_{ \stackrel{S\subseteq N-\{i\}}{ \text{and} \mid S \mid=j } }  
=\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}   \binom{n-1}{j} . 
\end{eqnarray*}